# JS doesn't recognizes function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have the problem that even while I call a Function from a different JS-Script correctly I get the error that that function doesn't exist.
I have following function in stopwatch.js:

```
function timeOut() {
        return time;
    }
```

This function is part of a constructor function and time is a variable is that function.

I call it like this in main.js:

```
time = watch.timeOut();
```

watch is the object I created using the constructor function.

I have both scripts in index.html like this at the end of the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stopwatch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

now i get following error code:

```
main.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: watch.time is not a function
```

I can't find the reason why this is happening

This is the snippet I stripped it down to the problem:

```js
//stopwatch.js
function stopwatch() {
  var time = 3254; //Example Time
  
  function timeOut() {
        return time;
  }
}

//main.js
var watch = new stopwatch();
var time;

time = watch.timeOut();
console.log(time);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stopwatch.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Something to add is that I have other functions in stopwatch.js and calling them just works fine.

Comment: Where is `watch`? Where is `time`?

Comment: This is not very clear. What is and where is watch?

Comment: we need a lot more code, we'll help you out

Comment: Btw guys, it's a new member, don't go downvoting like that so soon.

Comment: Please update your question with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the [<>] toolbar button; here's how to do one). – https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: I'm writing the snippet now  I just have the question is there a way to simulate multiple JS Scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  The `timeOut` function is declared within the scope of the `stopwatch` function, but there's nothing indicating that it should be visible from outside of that scope.  A simple way to do that in this case would be to set it to a property on `this` within the `stopwatch` function.  Something like this:

```js
function stopwatch() {
    var time = 3254; //Example Time
      
    this.timeOut = function() {
        return time;
    };
}

var watch = new stopwatch();
var time = watch.timeOut();
console.log(time);
```

Comment: Works now, Thanks a lot!